# How to use PushState routers in Backbone.js

Tags: model-view-controller, html, backbone.js, router, pushstate

I am using a router below

```
App.Router.PersonRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "": "homepage",
        "/p/:id": "getpost",
        "/p/:id/*file": "download"
    },
    homepage: function () {
        alert("requesting home page");
    },
    getpost: function (id) {
        alert("Requested post with id " + id);
    },
    download: function (id, file) {
        alert("person with id " + id + " is requesting file " + file);
    }
});
```

and started to try `HTML5 pushState` option in backbone.js. by doing below.since the files are served from index.html file. It is just that `alerts` do not show when using HTML5 pushstate api but happily does when using hashbang url's.

```
Backbone.history.start({pushState:true,root:"index.html"});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `root` option in `Backbone.history.start` is a path not a resource.

Also make sure you kill the leading `/` in your routes, so `"p/:id"` instead of `"/p/:id"`
This should get you going.

Comment: i need the leading `/` because the url's naturally look `/#/p/3` does the character interfere with working of pushState api? Could you explain more on `root` documentation is sparse about this, so when using root does a router match for `index.html/#/p/3` ?

Comment: You don't need the leading `/`. All paths should be relative to your root. Your server should reply appropriately at /root, /root/p/3 /root/p/3/somefile.txt . Then it will work uniformly with pushState or not.

Comment: now that's not possible with stupidest web server (IIS) ,`Your server should reply appropriately at /root, /root/p/3 /root/p/3/somefile.txt ` we are in stone age of technology using Microsoft web products even now

Comment: well while I can't agree more about your characterization of the IIS, surely it's possible even for IIS to serve more than a single URI?

Comment: at the least with IIS 7 i suppose for that i need Professional versions of their operating systems lol. I will mark this as answer since you cleared the doubt

Comment: IIS7 has rewriting built in. ASP.NET has routing built in as well. One or the other will probably suffice. I don't believe there is a "pro" version of IIS, though they used to cap the number of simultaneous connections on non-server operating systems. 

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/496/iis-url-rewriting-and-aspnet-routing/